# How to include Background images for android apps

Tags: android

I have designed a background images for my layout and for my list view  with the 6 different DPI scales, now how can i included them in my project cause the image assets configuration has only luncher , navigation & tabs & notifications icons (not images) .

(how to include and tell android that i have background image for each screen ??)

any suggestions will be much appreciated

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put images for different densities (alternate resource files) in different folders which contains density qualifier in their names.

Like in:

- drawable
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-xhdpi

To create such folders in Android Studio:

1. Right click on resource folder ('res') or click on File menu
2. New > Android resource directory
3. Change resource type to 'drawable'
4. Add (>>) 'Density' from available qualifiers
5. Choose required density qualifier from the dropped list on right side
6. and click ok

OR

1. Right click on resource folder ('res')
2. New > Directory
3. Type 'drawable' with required qualifier (ex. drawable-xhdpi)

Read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) for more details

Answer (score 1):

you have to create following folders under res directory

```
drawable-ldpi  //For low density screens
drawable-mdpi   //For medium density screens
drawable-hdpi   // For high resolution screens
drawable-xhdpi   //For extra high resolution screens
drawable-xxhdpi  //for extra extra high resolution screens
drawable-xxxhdpi  // for extra extra extra high resolution screens
```

place the back ground in the respective folder with same name , android studio will automatically pick the image depending on dpi of screen

example image  https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-4329884d446f1f9246d61979487e9baf

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to tell android it will know once you put them in specific folder.

Right click on res click resource file then go for draw able. From the left box pick density and select different specialties and make folders.

Once done paste the respective images in the respective folders